# Iframe inside PhoneGap App will not load a PHP page

Tags: html, iframe, cordova

I am creating an iPad app, using HTML5 and PhoneGap. I am wanting to put an iframe into a page and pull through some content in a php page found remotely on our server.

I have set the correct ExternalHost in the PhoneGap.plist file so that it will accept the external domain.

If I tell the iframe to access a .html page (on the server), it works perfectly - However if I change the extension to .php I get a blank iframe.

**This is all while testing the app directly on the iPad and the IOS Simulator.**

Could anyone suggest anything I have missed out?

Comment: Is it the same for all servers? Could it be an issue with this specific server?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. I tried an example that I found online. I linked it directly to his php page for testing and it worked. I've spent ages going through Google trying to find out if there are settings I need to get changed on the server, but can't find anything...

Comment: This is happening because of cross origin policy. You need to allow the cross origin request using php headers on your target php page